# Indentation of Error Handler in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, error-handling, vba

This is a very fussy question: I am inserting an Error Handler in a `For To` loop in Excel VBA; I want the content of the loop indented, such that:

```
For i = 0 to n
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
        '~~> code here
    ErrorHandler:
        '~~> code here
        Resume NextLoop
    NextLoop:
Next
```

However, Excel VBA automatically cancels indentation of Error Handlers:

```
For i = 0 to n
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
        '~~> code here
ErrorHandler:
        '~~> code here
        Resume NextLoop
NextLoop:
Next
```

I have tried to unselect option "Auto Indent" in "Tools" > "Options" > "Editor" but this hasn't worked.

**How can I avoid this?**

Comment: You can't control the indentation of labels in Excel. It is defaulted and fixed on the left. The reason for that is to make them easier to spot

Comment: I see @Victor Moraes. Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: I honestly don't know, but may I ask why would you want to do that, other than "I think it's prettier that way"?

Comment: _"Circumvent"_... Rewrite to handle the errors another way without `Goto` statements.

Comment: That's really the only reason @Victor Moraes, that's why I said it was a "_fussy question_". Ok, thanks.

Comment: I agree with @PortlandRunner on this one. Avoid the usage of `GoTo` is the best advice here :)

Comment: Not a fussy question at all. It is a major pain when the IDE makes decisions and you have to obey.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**  There was a careless mistake in the original code.  Thank you  user2426679 for giving me the opportunity to fix it.

**Original post**

Code that uses `GoTo Label` can be a nightmare to understand and get error free.  The only situation I know off in which `GoTo Label` might be appropriate is a fatal error exit where there is no intention to return.  Jumping out of an error and trying to jump back is very difficult to get right and very difficult to understand when you return to it in a few months.

Is there more than one statement in your code that can throw an error?  If so, how does the error handler know which error it is handling?

I favour:

```
On Error Resume Next                ' Suspend normal error handling
Statement that might throw an error
On Error GoTo 0                     ' Restore normal error handling
If Err.Number <> 0 then
  ' Code to handle error
End If
```

The value of `Err.Number` and `Err.Description` will tell what the error is and allow to write specific error handling code.

Some argue that taking error handling out of the main code keeps the main code clean.  There is some merit in this argument.  If there are dozens of potential errors, the analysis can become complicated and make the normal path difficult to isolate. But, in my experience, this is very unusual.  Perhaps, you have a list of files some of which might not open.  There are lots of reasons why a file does open but your code can do nothing about them.  All it can do is display `Err.Description` and move onto the next file.

**New text and code**

Apart from the mistake in the code there is nothing in my original post that I now consider incorrect.  However, I do not think the original post was as complete as it should be.

If you search for “VBA Err.Number” you will find sites that list VBA’s error handling codes.  Since these sites come and go, I will not recommend my favourite.  However, I try to generate errors to see what happens.  Consider this code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DemoErrorHandling()

  Dim ErrDesc As String
  Dim ErrNum As Long
  Dim FileNum As Long
  Dim PathFile As Variant

  FileNum = FreeFile

  For Each PathFile In Array("", "X:", "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\" & _
                             "WirelessCommon\libeay32.dll")

    On Error Resume Next
    Open PathFile For Input As FileNum
    ErrNum = Err.Number
    ErrDesc = Err.Description
    Close FileNum
    On Error GoTo 0
    Debug.Print """" & PathFile & """ gives error:"
    Debug.Print "  A " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Debug.Print "  B " & ErrNum & " " & ErrDesc

  Next

End Sub
```

Which, on my system, outputs:

```
"" gives error:
  A 0 
  B 75 Path/File access error
"X:" gives error:
  A 0 
  B 76 Path not found
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\libeay32.dll" gives error:
  A 0 
  B 0
```

Note, as user2426679 pointed out, `On Error GoTo 0`has cleared `Err.Number` and `Err.Description`.  Only by saving these values in variables are they available for testing.  Note, attempting to open an empty file name and a non-existent disc give different errors.

My code demonstrates that you can loop trying different files until one opens successfully.  You could keep asking the user for a file until one opened without an error.

Comment: This will not work: `Err.Number` gets reset after `On Error GoTo 0`

Comment: @user2426679  Thanks for the heads-up.  Do you think my edit adequately corrects my error?

Comment: *yes*, but I generally detest VBA's error handling (lack thereof), because (1) MS documentation is hardly comprehensive enough to know all of the error numbers, which is why you have to resort to the "number discovery" that you did above, and (2) this forces one into a position where the code usually becomes equivalent to `try ... catch(all)`, which you'd *never* do in another language.  Because of this, I opt to put no more than a single line of code in between an `On Error GoTo myHandler` and an `On Error GoTo 0`; I just have to be 100% confident in the erroring line between those.

Comment: @user2426679  I agree, VBA's error handling is clumsy and I test for as many possible errors as I can to avoid needing  it.  Like you I only test one statement at a time when I have no choice but to include it..